# Exported MySQL database without procedures by mistake

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've exported a database via SSH and I didn't add `--routine` command to export the routines.

Now I don't have any access to this database, and I have only one .sql file. is there any way to restore and find the routines through PHP code or database structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry, in this case I think you're out of luck. Looking at the database structure, you won't be able to figure out what a routine might have done. Likewise, looking at the PHP code is probably not going to help. If you know what the routines did (for instance, manipulate data on insert, maintenance by deleting some rows, or some such) you can work through recreating it, but that's basically reverse engineering it based on what breaks when you try to run your application.